# Mapping user/group from host to docker container

Tags: php, apache, docker

I want to develop some php and use docker for php containers. What I'm interested in running php code & tailing php log. Looking at docker hub I found php image https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ which is pretty much what I want.

However I entered in file permissions problems when using this image with mapped volumes (`-v` option in `docker run`).

In my local development folder file permissions are set up 1000:100 while in docker image it's accessed with 33:33 what is with www-data user and group. The www-data:www-data is default one for apache web server to access the data.

One possibility is tell apache to run as new user, however this option have shortcoming since I'm working in a team and hardcoding userid's would complicate things further.

How can I make this transition seamless, that is map file permissions accordingly?

I want to map permissions 1000:100 (UID:GID) from my local user to www-data:www-data in container space.

I run following command as reference:

`docker run -d --name server -p 8080:80 -v $(PWD):/var/www/html php:7-apache`

Comment: Hi, did you every solve this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember anymore. I think I gave up and improvised otherwise I'd post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with modified httpd.conf and mount that to the run cmd:

```
docker run -dit --name h2 -p 8082:80 -v /home/core/my-www:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/:ro -v /home/core/myConf/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:ro httpd:latest
```

Could not get this to work: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/14

My httpd.conf

```
#User daemon
#Group daemon
###Tilo MOD
User #1000
Group #100
```